# I want to drag object along z axis with touch in unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch

I want to use unity3d and Vector3 drag object with touch on z-axis(Android)
How would I do can you help me?

Comment: Worst question ever and you should have added more details in order to verify your problem. Please, make your question be more detailed by case.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var touch : Touch in Input.touches){
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began){
            //touch.position.x
        //touch.position.y              
        }    
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved){
            //
    }
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended){
            //
    }   
}
```

Its a basic way to get touches. So basicly u can store touch position when it started and then u can check when the touch moves. So it ll give u 2 different touch position as pixels. After that u can compare this positions and u can decide that where the touch moves. Left, right or any other direction. And to drag it i belive u can use something like this "transform.position +=Vector3.up * ("difference between 2 touch point") * Time.deltaTime;"